# Python 3.5 sqlite3 passing parameter of string - Incorrect number of bindings supplied

Tags: python, sqlite

Error:

> c = dbConnection.execute("SELECT compid FROM " + tableToUse + " WHERE
>   id = ?", id)
>       sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 2 supplied.

When I do:

```
def getcompid (dbConnection, tableToUse, id):
    c = dbConnection.execute("SELECT compid FROM " + tableToUse + " WHERE id = ?", id)

manualcompid = [('8','from01'),('35','28')]
for manid in manualcompid:

    ERROR:
    foundid = getcompid (dbConnection, tableToUse, manid[0])

    OR SAME ERROR:

    r = str(manid[0])
    foundid = getcompid (dbConnection, tableToUse, r)


    THE BELOW IS FINE:
    foundid = getcompid (dbConnection, tableToUse, '8')
```

It seams to me `r` should be 'simple' `string` same as '8', and more `manid[0]` is a string already. Why error?

Why I have to use: `foundid = getcompid (dbConnection, tableToUse, (manid[0],))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bindings need to be in a list or tuple. Try this:

```
c = dbConnection.execute(
    "SELECT compid FROM " + tableToUse + " WHERE id = ?", [id])
```

Comment: Thank you. My question is then why it worked with '8'? Python implicitly changed it to list maybe?